# Confusion with Cout in c++

Tags: c++, increment, cout, prefix, postfix-operator

As printing will start from left side to right side in cout function, why these types of commands printing differently? please explain me. According to my knowledge the output of the following program should be 113 but it is 322. How?

```
#include<iostream.h>
void main()
{
int i=1;
cout<<i<<i++<<++i;
}
```

Output:

322

### Thanks in Advance.

Comment: Maybe this can help http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3986361/behavior-of-post-increment-in-cout

Comment: This looks like an issue with [sequence points](http://stackoverflow.com/q/4176328/3747990), see [this as well](http://stackoverflow.com/q/1895922/3747990).

Comment: This code invokes undefined behavior. See [Undefined Behavior and Sequence Points](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4176328).

Comment: I hate it when somebody says that **"It is undefined :("**

Comment: Look at this : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/665112/how-the-buffer-of-cout-work

Comment: If you use `x++` or `++x` in a statement, don't use `x` elsewhere in the statement.

Answer (score 0):

You seem to be assuming that the increments happen from left to right, but according to the Standard, the order of evaluation of subexpressions is *unspecified*. See [here](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/eval_order) for more details.

In this case, it looks like the compiler chose to evaluate from right to left:

- `++i` happens, so `i == 2` and `2` is the value of the expression;
- `i++` happens, incrementing `i` to `3` but evaluating to its old value, `2`;
- `i` is now evaluated as `3`.